# Get high precision output from shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, fragment-shader

I want to render high precision float values to a texture, but the values I read are clamped to [0, 1]. Is there anyway to get unclamped values?

Here is the fragment portion of the shader code:

```
float4 frag (v2f i) : SV_TARGET
{
    return float4(0.098, 0.698, 200, 100000); // Obviously a contrived example.
}
```

Here is the code creating the texture to render to:

```
RenderTextureDescriptor rtd = new RenderTextureDescriptor(1, 1, RenderTextureFormat.ARGBFloat);
RenderTexture rt = RenderTexture.GetTemporary(rtd);
RenderTexture.active = rt;

mainCamera.SetReplacementShader(selectionShader, "");
mainCamera.Render(); // OnPostRender will be called
mainCamera.ResetReplacementShader();
```

Read code (in `OnPostRender`):

```
Texture2D hitTexture = new Texture2D(1, 1, TextureFormat.RGBAFloat, false);
Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, 1, 1);
hitTexture.ReadPixels(rect, 0, 0, false);

Color pixelSample = hitTexture.GetPixel(0, 0);
Debug.Log("Sample: " + pixelSample);
```

The output is "RGBA(0.098, 0.698, 1.000, 1.000)", rather than "RGBA(0.098, 0.698, 200, 100000)" as hoped/expected.

Comment: I think that `Color pixelSample` (or `texture2d.GetPixel()`) will cap any values over 1 because they don't make sense in a RGBA scale. In a very very simple way to put it, is like you have a variable that is an integer and assign a value of `1.3` to that variable,, if you print that, it will be `1`, not `1.3`.

Comment: That seems to be the case. As `GetPixel` returns a `Color`, it appears to be useless here. Is there another way to read the value?

Comment: I think that you can use [Material.GetVector()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.GetVector.html)

Comment: That's for properties, no?

Comment: yes, but I think that you should be able to update that property and read it when you need it,

Comment: The value that I read (in the real example, not the above contrived example) is per fragment. Properties are static across all fragments. (I'm coming from a OpenGL background, so I'm assuming a little here.) Hmm, but if I render only one fragment... I'll have to think about it.

Comment: You can use [GetRawTextureData()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetRawTextureData.html) to read back your float. I suggest avoiding reading back any data from the GPU, however. It introduces a synchronization point and has a large performance impact. Doing that every frame, even if it's just a single float, will absolutely affect your framerate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40128185/read-float-values-from-rgbafloat-texture-in-unity-3d

Comment: I ran across `GetRawTextureData()` and tried using it. It seemingly returns the same values as `GetPixels` which leads me to believe that the underlying texture itself is clamped.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextureFormat.ARGB32.html Not for the RenderTexture, however, it states here that the ARGB32 texture format consists of four 8-bit values, that are mapped between [0,1]. Most probably, RenderTextureFormat of ARGB32 follows the same convention.